# btrfs convert raid 5 to 1 with usage filter possible?

Tags: raid, software-raid, btrfs

does btrfs support converting the filesystem partially?

I am currently in this state:

```
btrfs fi df .
Data, RAID5: total=9.83TiB, used=7.68TiB
System, RAID1: total=32.00MiB, used=704.00KiB
Metadata, RAID1: total=12.00GiB, used=8.61GiB
GlobalReserve, single: total=512.00MiB, used=0.00B
```

And due to the bugs found in raid5 mode, I want to migrate to raid1. There are various reasons, for not doing the complete conversion right now. I want to set the target mode to raid1. So any new data will be put in raid1 and when there is time, I can trigger a full re-balance (or soft)

So is something like this possible?

```
btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -dusage=10 .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as nobody else had any information I simply tried it and document my steps hereby.

```
btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -dusage=10 .
```

This command simply converted the chunks which met the filter(usage=10%). There was no compression of the chunks (like a regular balance) and no setting of the target raid level from raid5 to raid1. So this was fairly useless and it created big chunks with mostly empty data and wasted time.

The next approach was using the limit filter and soft parameter, to do the conversion step by step.

```
btrfs balance start -dconvert=raid1 -dlimit=500,soft .
```

Thus the file system was converted step by step.

Notes:

1. balance "empty chunks" away before conversion. This saves time.
2. during this process btrfs will put new data always into chunks of the old raid-profile. I found no way to change this. So new data will always be put into raid5 chunks or new raid5 chunks are created to hold the data. Once the whole file system is converted, this behavior is of course gone.
3. this completely worked online :)